# Regex how can I merge execution

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace, merge

I have the following buffer returning from a .textContent

```
            Latitude

    

    32,6549581304256 

    

        Longitude

    

    -16,9288643331225
```

I fixed the whitespaces with
dwText = Regex.Replace( dwText, @"\s{2,}", "\n"); resulting in

```
Latitude
32,6549581304256
Longitude
-16,9288643331225
```

I then transformed this new output to my needs by
dwText = Regex.Replace( dwText, @"(Latitude|Longitude)(.*)\n", "$1: "); resulting in

```
Latitude: 32,6549581304256
Longitude: -16,9288643331225
```

My question is can i do these 2 lines in one go?

```
dwText = Regex.Replace( dwText, @"\s{2,}", "\n");
dwText = Regex.Replace( dwText, @"(Latitude|Longitude)(.*)\n", "$1: ");
```

I would appreciate some help on how this can be achieved more efficiently, thank you.

Comment: You can try the regex: `(?i)\s*(Latitude)\s*([\d-,.+]+)\s*(Longitude)\s*([\d-,.+]+)` and Replacement: `$1: $2\n$3: $4`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (with `i` flag),

```regex
[\S\s]*?([a-z]+)[\S\s]*?([-\d,]+)[\S\s]*?
```

*Replacement:* `$1: $2\n`

[C# Regex Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cS%5cs%5d*%3f%28%5ba-z%5d%2b%29%5b%5cS%5cs%5d*%3f%28%5b-%5cd%2c%5d%2b%29%5b%5cS%5cs%5d*%3f&i=++++++++++++Latitude%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++32%2c6549581304256+%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++Longitude%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++-16%2c9288643331225+&r=%241%3a+%242%5cn&o=i)

---

### Explanation

- `[\S\s]*?` - matches *anything* lazily.
- `[a-z]+` (first capture group) - matches alphabetical words, case insensitive.
- `[-\d,]+` (second capturing group) - matches digits, `-` (hyphen) and `,` (comma)

Comment: Hahaha that was fast and perfect! TYVM sir. ( I wish I could understand what you did with regex ).

Comment: Detailed matching with colors can be [found here](https://regex101.com/r/hYeIGm/2), though it's PCRE, but works the same, for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the whitespace chars around the Latitude and Longitude and capture the values in 2 groups and use those 2 groups in the replacement.

```
\s*\b(Latitude|Longitude)\s*(-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `\b(Latitude|Longitude)` A word boundary, capture either latitude or Longitude in group 1
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(-?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?)` Capture group 2, match optional `-`, 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

Replace with:

```
$1: $2\n
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%5cb%28Latitude%7cLongitude%29%5cs*%28-%3f%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%3f%29%5cb&i=++++++++++++Latitude%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++32%2c6549581304256+%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++Longitude%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%0d%0a++++-16%2c9288643331225+&r=%241%3a+%242%0d%0a&o=i)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not parse the values out and then extract them to do what is needed with them?

By using match group named captures `(?<{NameHere}> )` one can organize and then extract the data.

**Example** *white space shortened, but it works across lines and with the original example*:

```
var data    = " Latitude  32,6549  Longitude  -16,9288 ";
var pattern = @"[^\d]+(?<Lat>[\d,]+)[^\d]+(?<Long>[\d,]+)";

var mtch = Regex.Match(data, pattern);

Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {mtch.Groups["Lat"].Value} Longitude: {mtch.Groups["Long"].Value}");

// Latitude: 32,6549 Longitude: 16,9288
```